# rollover image using mouseover onmousedown, onmousemove, onmouseout, onmouseup

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to share my problem here I hope you can help me.I should create a rollover image that should be 100x100 I did this I think.Now when user will move out from this image will come a new image(lets calling it

1. When user moves on the initial picture and he press on it will appear a new image
2. When user is on the initial image but not he press on it with the mouse it will appear a new image(lets calling it.
3. More practical way to explain when you press with the mouse the image a new image will come, when you go out from the image new image will appear and when you are having your mouse (with not pressing the mouse) a new image will come. I hope you understanding it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <img onmouseover="insideImg(this)" onmouseout="outsImg(this)"  width="100" height="100">


    <script>
    function insideImg(x) {
       src="smiley.gif"
     alt="Smiley"
    }

    function outImg(x) {
       //another image
    }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has to be a homework problem.  Why don't you try some code and when you get stuck, ask a specific question?

Comment: i think its specific question.I dont know how to change image with this ,ok no problem i will look somewhere else

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: to upload all my history of my google chrome?

Comment: You can probably use css pseudoclasses like :hover and :active to change the src of the image.